# FactoryGirl association_id is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to use factory_girl with associations. I have 2 models: account_info and person. AccountInfo belongs to a persons o my account_info factory looks like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account_info do
    entity_type 1
    account_key { Faker::Twitter.user[:id] }
    association :entity_id, factory: [:person]
    association :social_media_site_id, factory: [:twitter]
  end
end
```

Per documentation:

```
You can also specify a different factory or override attributes:

factory :post do
  # ...
  association :author, factory: :user, last_name: "Writely"
end
The behavior of the association method varies depending on the build strategy used for the parent object.

# Builds and saves a User and a Post
post = create(:post)
post.new_record?        # => false
post.author.new_record? # => false

# Builds and saves a User, and then builds but does not save a Post
post = build(:post)
post.new_record?        # => true
post.author.new_record? # => false
```

It creates the record Person but the AccountInfo entity_id remains nil. Why?

```
d = FactoryGirl.create(:account_info)
d.reload
  AccountInfo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "account_infos".* FROM "account_infos" WHERE "account_infos"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 443], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<AccountInfo id: 443, entity_type: "legislator", account_key: "498133264559673104", social_media_site_id: nil, entity_id: nil, created_at: "2018-04-29 13:18:49", updated_at: "2018-04-29 13:18:49">
```

Versions:

```
factory_girl_rails (4.9.0)
rails (5.1.6)
ruby (2.5.0)
```

Comment: association should be `entity` not `entity_id`

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `entity=' for #<AccountInfo:0x00007f81a8b16580>
Did you mean?  entity_id=) if i do that

Comment: Do you have the association defined on your `AccountInfo` model? (eg `belongs_to :entity`) ?

Comment: Yes, but this I don't think matters

Comment: However your answer made me think and you are completely right. It was something among those lines. Please post this answer, it's enough :D @TarynEast

Comment: :D glad it was helpful. I thought it odd that that method is undefined... that speaks to something else being the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's odd that `entity=` is not defined. Do you have the association defined on your AccountInfo model? (eg `belongs_to :entity`)? If so, that could be the problem (or something similar).